# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] p = (i + 1) * 100;

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, type-conversion, integer

I am trying to fill array with the numbers without using `scanf`. I encountered  warning: `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

```
p = (i + 1) * 100;
  ^
```

and when i try to print the array the array output random values. How do i solve it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nums[8], i;
    int *p;
    p = nums;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        p = (i + 1) * 100;
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*p = (i + 1) * 100;`

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't add a cast**.

Comment: Use array syntax. `p[i] = (i+1)*100;`

Comment: @Lundin Why not `nums[i] = ...`? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Too easy and too readable, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer

```
int *p;
p = nums;
```

and then instead of assigning the element of the array pointed to by the pointer you are trying to assign the pointer itself with an integer value.

```
p = (i + 1) * 100;
```

It is evident that you mean

```
*p = (i + 1) * 100;
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use the magic number `8` in the for loop. It is better to use a named constant.

If you want to fill the array using a pointer in the for loop then the program can look the following way

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 8 };

    int nums[N];

    int init_value = 1;
    for ( int *p = nums; p != nums + N; ++p )
    {
        *p = 100 * init_value++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using this approach you can write a separate function that will initialize an array the following way

```
void init_array( int *a, size_t n, int value )
{
    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        *p = 100 * value++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the assignment `p = (i + 1) * 100`, `p` is an `int *`, not an `int`, so the assignment would convert the integer `(i + 1) * 100` to a pointer. Instead, use `*p = (i + 1) * 100`.

Comment: There's no casting. There is a *conversion*, but it's a conversion of the result of `(i + 1) * 100` to match the type of `p` (i.e. the result of `(i + 1) * 100` is converted to an `int *`), not the other way around.